# evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty} (3x^2-x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}+x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> $$\lim _{x\to \infty} (3x^2-x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}+x$$

can I look at $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} (3^{\frac{1}{3}}x^{\frac{2}{3}}-x+x)$?

Comment: No, you cannot -- exponentiation is not distributive..

Comment: ...by which Clement means "exponentation does not distribute over addition and subtraction"; it distributes just fine over multiplication.

Comment: For large $x$ this involves the cube root of a negative number.  Taking the "principal value" for that cube root, your quantity is not real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\left(1+z\right)^{1/3}=1+\frac13 z+O(z^2) \tag 1$$

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the full solution

> $$\begin{align}x+\left(3x^2-x^3\right)^{1/3}&=x-x\left(1-\frac{3x^2}{x^3}\right)^{1/3}\\\\&=x-x\left(1-\frac3x\right)^{1/3}\\\\&=x-x\left(1-\frac1x+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)\\\\&=1+O\left(\frac1x\right)\to 1\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Where did $1$ came from on the last move?

Comment: $x-x+x\times \frac1x$.

Comment: is $$\left(1+z\right)^{1/3}=1+\frac13 z+O(z^2) \tag 1$$
 come from binomial?

Where does $\frac{1}{3z}$ come from?

Comment: Yes, the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalisations) was developed in 1665 by Newton.

Answer (score 3):

Set $x=\frac1h$, then the limit transforms to
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-(1-3h)^{1/3}}h
$$
which is the derivative of $f(x)=(1+3x)^{1/3}$ at $x=0$.

Or 3 times the derivative of $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ at $x=1$

Comment: can you explain the move from $x$ to $\frac{1}{h}$ ?

Comment: It is sometimes advantageous to replace a limit to infinity by a limit to 0, since you can properly compute with $0$, but not with $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it'll probably give you the wrong answer. In general, it's *not* true that 
$$
(a + b)^k = a^k + b^k
$$
but you're using that idea in trying to simplify the parenthesized expression.

To see that it doesn't generally work, look at 
$$
(2 + 2)^3 = 64 \\
2^3 + 2^3 = 16. 
$$

Comment: Of course, the equality holds if $a$ or $b$ $=0$ and $k \ne 0$.

Comment: right..but so what? In simplifying an expression, you can't use a rule that has preconditions like $a = 0$ unless you know that $a = 0$, so rules like this are seldom helpful (esp. when the preconditions limit you to a measure 0 portion of the domain).

Comment: Of course, I know that this is a very trivial statement, I was to specify the general cases in which this equality holds. E

Comment: You missed the cases where $k$ is odd and $a+b = 0$, And there are probably others, too.

Comment: If a+b=0, why does k have to be odd?

Comment: Because $0 = (2 -2)^2 \ne 2^2 + (-2)^2 = 8$.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

By factoring, the expression becomes $(x^2(3-x))^{1/3}+x=x^{2/3}(3-x)^{1/3}+x$. Now we take a seemingly random detour and multiply the numerator and denominator by $1/x$, giving $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{-1/3}(3-x)^{1/3}+1}{1/x}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{(-1){1/3}}(3-x)^{1/3}+1}{1/x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(\frac{3-x}{x})^{1/3}+1}{1/x}$$

Taking x $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ gives the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$.

Applying L'Hopital's Rule gives

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{3}(\frac{3-x}{x})^{-2/3}(\frac{-3}{x^2})}{-1/x^2}.$$

After cancelling like terms, we find

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{3}{x}-1)^{2/3}=((-1)^2)^{-1/3}=1.$$